# Search and replace with “match words only” option

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I need to replace all [determiners](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/determiners/) from sentence. My problem that when i replace "a", it replace this letter in word.

`str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("a", withString: "")`

For example:
`a match a`

The result will be:
`mtch`

But i want: `match`

Comment: What's your expected result ?

Comment: result should be: ```match```

Comment: If their engine supports _assertions_, use a regex like this `(?<!\S)a(?!\S)` for a better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whole words with `\b` word boundary, and also, you can grab optional whitespace after these words with `\s*` (1+ whitespace). Then, we can make sure no leading spaces are left with `.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())`.

Also note that strings in Swift are C strings (support escape sequences) and since the regex special metacharacters need to be escaped with a literal backslash, you need to actually double the backslashes in the pattern (i.e. `\s` -> `"\\s"`).

Here is Swift 2.1 sample code:

```
var s = "a match a"
var out_s = ""
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\ba\\b\\s*", options: .CaseInsensitive) {
    out_s = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(s, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, s.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
    print("\""+out_s.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
        NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
    )+"\"")
}
```

It prints `"match"`.

Note also that `options: .CaseInsensitive` will perform a case insensitive match, use `options: []` to make the search case sensitive.

Now, if you have a list of the determiners, use *alternation*:

```
"\\b(?:an?|the)\\b\\s*"
```

This expression will match `a`, `an` or `the` followed with 0+ whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with word boundaries like this `/\ba\b/`. Should use `g` global search and case insensitive `i` flags.

Word boundary `\b` makes sure that there is no character followed or preceded by `a`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8lX4/3)**

Comment: can you provide example on swift ?

Comment: @Arti: Sorry am not a swift programmer.